# UITableViewController static cells not appearing when pushed to navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm running into a rut...
I've create a UITableViewController with static cells (i've deleted all default UITableView methods). Whenever I segue to this view controller, the static cells appear, but when I push it onto the navigationcontroller the static cells do not appear...any idea to why this would be hapenning?

Here is my code:

```
//shows empty uitableviewcontroller 
OthersUsersTableViewController *tvc = [[OthersUsersTableViewController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc
                                     animated:YES];
```

and

```
//works
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toOtherUser" sender:self];
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually alloc and init your Static table view, how should your app know that it is referencing a static table view in your storyboard?

Give your static table view an Identifier in the storyboard and initialize it like this:

```
OthersUsersTableViewController *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"staticTableView"];
```

You can set your identifier in the menu on the right where you also set the custom class for the view controller. The field is called Storyboard ID.

Comment: With that being said? how would i go about doing a custom initialization for that view controller?

Comment: What do you mean? Just replace your `alloc init` with the code I provided. Then push it onto your navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

when you're just calling [[UIViewController alloc] init], the UI objects you've added and configured on the storyboard,does not get called or wired to your view controller.

You should instantiate the view controller through the storyboard itself by adding an identifier to your view controller(on the storyboard) and calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method of your storyboard.
You can get a reference to your storyboard through the current view controller's storyboard property.

```
OthersUsersTableViewController *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```